# Unit Tests failing due to MismatchReportingTestListener

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am facing a weird issue where my unit tests are failing/succeeding on retrying. I previously wrote unit test case for 2 classes in my package and when I wrote the unit test cases for third class the test cases for the other two classes also start failing due to errors listed below

Errors in generated test Report:

Error 1

```
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'chunkedSnapshot' of type 'class
com.XXXX.YYY.lambda.ChunkedSnapshot'. You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so
I tried to construct the instance. However the constructor or the initialization block threw an 
exception : null
```

Error 2

```
Problems adding Mockito listener. Listener of type 'MismatchReportingTestListener' has already
been added and not removed. It indicates that previous listener was not removed according to the
API. When you add a listener, don't forget to remove the listener afterwards: Mockito.framework().removeListener(myListener); For more information, see the javadoc for 
RedundantListenerException class.
```

Some error in console which I feel might be relevant

```
  [junit] Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'chunkedSnapshot' of type 'class com.XXXX.YYYY.lambda.ChunkedSnapshot'.
    [junit] You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
    [junit] However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
```

The weird thing is that the test cases sometimes succeed, sometimes do not.

I will paste down the initialization piece of the third class and unit test class for same which is causing this issue

```
@Log4j2
public class ChunkedSnapshot implements RequestHandler<String, String> {
    private final AmazonAthena amazonAthena;
    private AthenaQueryExecutor athenaQueryExecutor;

    private final String snapshotDate;
    private final String tableName;
    private final String databaseName;
    private final String currentTable;
    private final String externalS3Location;
    private final String workGroup;
    private String buyableDate;

    public ChunkedSnapshot() {
        this(new LambdaConfiguration(System.getenv()));
    }
    public ChunkedSnapshot(LambdaConfiguration lambdaConfiguration) {
        this(lambdaConfiguration.getAmazonAthena());
    }

    public ChunkedSnapshot(AmazonAthena amazonAthena) {
        this.amazonAthena = amazonAthena;
        ConfigInitializer.initializeConfig();
        snapshotDate = LocalDate.now().toString();
        tableName = AppConfig.findString(ATHENA_MAIN_TABLE);
        databaseName = AppConfig.findString(ATHENA_DATABASE);
        workGroup = AppConfig.findString(ATHENA_WORKGROUP);
        currentTable = AppConfig.findString(CURRENT_TABLE);
        externalS3Location = AppConfig.findString(TABLE_S3_LOCATION);
        athenaQueryExecutor = new AthenaQueryExecutor();
    }
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String event, Context context) {
     //some content here
    }...more content
```

Unit Test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChunkedSnapshotTests extends AbstractTestCase {
    @Mock
    Context mockContext;
    @Mock
    AthenaQueryExecutor mockAthenaQueryExecutor;
    @Mock
    AmazonAthena mockAmazonAthena;
    @InjectMocks
    ChunkedSnapshot chunkedSnapshot;
    List<Row> rowList;
    List<Datum> datumList;
    String event = "some test event";
    @Before
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
        rowList = new ArrayList<>();
        datumList = new ArrayList<>();
        Row row = new Row();
        Datum datum1 = new Datum();
        datum1.setVarCharValue("some val");
        Datum datum2 = new Datum();
        datum2.setVarCharValue("some val");
        datumList.add(datum1);
        datumList.add(datum2);
        row.setData(datumList);
        rowList.add(row);
        when(mockAthenaQueryExecutor.processResultRows(any(), any())).thenReturn(rowList);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandleRequest() {
        chunkedSnapshot.handleRequest(event, mockContext);
    }
    ..... more content
```

I feel there must be some problem in the initialization of the *InjectMocks* since this is the first class out of previous test classes which is using the inject mocks.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to [this github issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1767), which was fixed and merged. Try upgrading Mockito.